# data.table: force <NA> response

Tags: r, data.table

In my example:

```
library(data.table)
id <- 1:10
x <- rnorm(n=10,mean=10)
groups <- ifelse(x<5,"D","S")
df <- data.frame(id,x,groups)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ id    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ x     : num  9.28 9.68 11.64 11.33 9.34 ...
#  $ groups: chr  "S" "S" "S" "S" ...
setDT(df)[,id:=rleid(groups)][groups=="D",decision:=fifelse(1:.N>=3, "Combate","Monitora"), by=id][,.(groups,decision)]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df)[, `:=`(id, rleid(groups))], groups
> ==  :    Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 0 in column 'decision'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are
> ok)    or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the
> RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers
> of your code.

but I'd like as output if i don't have any `D` level:

```
#     groups decision
#  1:      S <NA>
#  2:      S <NA>
#  3:      S <NA>
#  4:      S <NA>
#  5:      S <NA>
#  6:      S <NA>
#  7:      S <NA>
#  8:      S <NA>
#  9:      S <NA>
# 10:      S <NA>
```

Please, any help with it?

Comment: `fifelse(seq_len(.N)>=3, "Combate","Monitora")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setDT(df)[,id:=rleid(groups)][groups=="D",decision:=fifelse(seq_len(.N)>=3, "Combate","Monitora"), by=id][,.(groups,decision)]
    groups decision
 1:      S     <NA>
 2:      S     <NA>
 3:      S     <NA>
 4:      S     <NA>
 5:      S     <NA>
 6:      S     <NA>
 7:      S     <NA>
 8:      S     <NA>
 9:      S     <NA>
10:      S     <NA>
```